# VBA/.NET: Creating an Outlook rule for Reply-to

Tags: .net, vba, outlook, outlook-addin

Using **VBA** or **.NET** for add-ins, is it possible to create an Outlook rule if the Reply-to contains a specific address?

My first problem is that the sender in the `from` field is different from the `reply-to` field. This is due to that the sender is sending an email through a mailing list.

There is [no documented reply-to rule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863417(v=office.14).aspx) in the VBA enumeration object according to the MSDN documentation. Example of a rule that exists:

```
olConditionSenderAddress
```

The following rule does not exist:

```
olConditionReplyTo
```

Preferably, I would like to solve this using VBA, but if not possible I could resort to creating an add-in .NET application. <strike>However, there appears to be [no `ReplyTo` property associated with the VBA `Mailitem` object.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-object-outlook)</strike>. There is, however, [a `MailMessage.ReplyTo` property in the .NET DOM hierarchy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.replyto(v=vs.110).aspx), but the API is listed as obsolete.

---

**EDIT:**  Apparently, `ReplyRecipientsName` is the correct VBA property to use.

Comment: @MitchWheat Did you read the tags? Last time I checked, Visual Basic for applications was a programming language.

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Clijsters I hope the updated question now better reflects StackOverflow policies. Otherwise, please let me know how I am in error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Application_ItemSend` event which fires when you press send button. You create this event in `ThisOutlookSession module`. Your event sub could look as below:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    With Item   'Item is your e-mail

        'to whom email
        Debug.Print .To
        'check if reply
        Debug.Print .ReplyRecipients.Count

        If .To = "ToEmail@Email" And .ReplyRecipients.Count > 0 Then
            'your logic
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I somehow missed the property while glancing through the documentation. Because I initially did not specify my question accurately enough, the solution I was looking for requires `ReplyRecipientsName`.